# Destination SMTP server does not want to receive message body

Tags: smtp

I am using software named send blaster, am using gmail smtp server but it does not allows me to send more then 500 mails, is there any one who knows how can i over come form this prob... need help is there any stmp server or software that can send unlimited mails.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue of your charset, select the correct charset when composing email in sendblaster, that is "windows-1252"

Comment: That fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

Google deliberately limits the number of emails that can be sent in a single session and over various timeframes. As you achieved 500 mails I suspect that you are already using one of their premium products - such as Google Apps for Enterprise.

Still, beware that email traffic is measured across the whole domain and that you may be restricting email for other users at your company, or sharing the Google Apps account.

To send batches of thousands of emails you will need a dedicated mailing list manager - search Google for lots of products. You will also have to make changes to your DNS records to prove that you are not sending spam.

To send unlimited numbers of messages, you will need access to a dedicated marketing service.

Answer (score -1):

<s>The Best Free mailing solution according to my experience is spark post which gives you 100k emails for free, But do remember when you're using free 3rd party services, you're using shared servers, therefore if other free users send spam from the shared ip, your mail will probably be sent to spam as well, hence I recommend Implementing your own smtp server or going for a paid plan.</s>

**UPDATE**

After some research it seems sparkpost no longer offer this free package. But there are no good alternatives. Closest I can find is [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/pricing), And best case scenario would be if you send from an AWS EC2 server in which case you get 62000 free mail per month [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/).

P.S : These are subject to change, and only valid at the time of the update. Down voting this post will not help change company policy.